# Oracle ADF Comparison 11g vs 12c and integrating with modern coding techniques

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-adf, oracle12c

My company is currently undergoing a transition to Oracle to replace our legacy supply chain management system.

Part of the transition will involve evaluating whether to use Oracle ADF or not. The main business drive for this is that it is under the Oracle banner. We have traditionally written all our web applications using Spring MVC, but want to evaluate (after an initial learning curve) whether it may be quicker to deliver apps that sit over the Oracle stack using ADF.

We are running Oracle 11g so think we will be restricted to ADF 11g. I've seen online demos for ADF 12c, but not so much on 11g.

Questions:

1. Is there a matrix to compare ADF over 11g and ADF over 12c?
2. What extras do you get with 12c and what may I be missing out if we are stuck with 11g?
3. How does ADF integrate with modern coding techniques like TDD / Continuous Integration / Maven Repositories? All projects in demos I've seen look like they have a flat structure and testing seems secondary.

I have searched the internet for advice and comparisons but to no avail. The lack of decent resources and forum activity on ADF as a whole is a bit of a concern too!

EDIT 28/11/15:
Thanks for all the replies so far...much appreciated.

With regards to the 11g and 12c debate. We are using Oracle Retail 14.1.1 and have possibly been advised that we must use ADF 11g as a lot of the software that belongs to Oracle Retail is at 11g (see table below). I appreciate that ADF 12c should work over the 11g database, so then is it a problem with just integrating with the other parts of Oracle retail? I am far from an expert when it comes to the rest of Oracle Retail.

Oracle Retail Release Version 14.1.1

Database 12.1

Fusion Middleware:

ADF 11.1.1.7

OAM 11.1.2.2

OID 11.1.1.7

WebLogic Server 10.3.6

OBIEE, ODI 11.1.1.7

Forms Server 11.1.2.2

SOA Suite 11.1.1.7

WebCenter Suite 11.1.1.9.0

Comment: ADF is a technology from the past. It's broken, slow, complex. Oracle support is bad, community is not active. Make your front-end with front-end technologies like Angular, and your backend with Spring. Check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530942/where-does-oracle-adf-11g-stands-among-java-ee-frameworks?rq=1

Comment: Note that Stackoverflow link is 3-5 years out of date. I agree that 10g and early 11g had issues. 12c is a much better product and I would take those comments with a grain of salt: You will note, *not everyone* agrees with the negative reviews, which are, for the most part, over generalized and mostly personal preference. As is Sydney's comment.

Comment: To be clear, I don't care what you choose, but choose based on verifiable, up to date data and criteria. This: "The main business drive for this is that it is under the Oracle banner." is significant. An experienced ADF developer can produce an app with DB & Web Service access, validation, calculations, edits, conversions, page flows, lists of values, very quickly. This may give you an idea about workflow:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/index-092757.html

Comment: @Sydney ADF had a shaky start, but it improved tremendously simply because Oracle used ADF as development platform for their "Oracle Fusion Applications" which consists of 5610 tables. Oracle used 3000 developers for the job.  Sure, you may call their technology outdated (XML based, stateful middle tier), but you can't call it broken or slow. In terms of community, please visit Oracle Forums - there are hundreds of messages daily. As far as documentation is concerned, better check Joe's post below - it probably has more documentation than all other java web frameworks combined.

Comment: 2 tables per developer ;) Joke aside, I had too many issues with that framework like inconsistent refresh (PPR), validation that occurs too early or too late. Performance is bad due to an old version of mojarra that you can't upgrade (https://blog.oio.de/2013/05/16/jsf-performance-mojarra-improves-dramatically-with-latest-release/). Passivation/Activation is a nightmare. Why bother with such a complex framework when you can get equivalent framework for free. OTN is a joke, most of answers are try that or try this because nobody really knows how it works. It's just my experience with ADF.

Comment: I kind of disagree with all your statements above, mostly with OTN being a joke. I see quite a few developers  posting on OTN that understand in dept how ADF works. Oracle provides the sources, there is no difference from an open source framework in terms of code access. 
Not sure if you were you visiting OTN recently.

Comment: Do you realize that Oracle 11g database has reached End Of Life support?  An upgrade to a non-obsolete version might be a good idea.  However, for the purposes of this question [ADF12c is compatible with 11g database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/121300-cert-2164864.html)

Answer (score 3):

I have been working with both 11g and 12c and I have to say that 12c (12.2.1.0.0) brings a [productivity boost](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/hotdeployment_in_jdeveloper_12c_don), from development perspective.
I won't see why anyone would start with 11g right now.

The biggest weakness of ADF comes from the fact that is a strange framework. I was used to jumping from one java web framework to another with relative ease. It wasn't the case with ADF. Though you may look you are having a fairly easy start, things will may get tricky after a while.

The key element is to understand the power behind Business Components and unfortunately this is the least understood element in ADF. I have never seen more bad code in my whole life, compared with other frameworks. But once correctly understood, ADF is head and shoulders above any framework in Java I know, when it comes to complex UI, data input screens, complex querying.

An advice: do not start your project without developers with proven ADF production experience. There quite a few ADF consultants around with lot of experience, they might be a bit expensive, but one of these guys can save you 50% of your development budget.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have seen this [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html) and [this one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/learnmore/index.html)? ADF is not dependent on DB version (up to a point), so you can certainly use ADF 12c against an 11g DB. Look at the [certification matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/122-cert-2708091.html) for guidance on supported DB versions. Oracle DB 10, 11, and 12 are all supported by 12c.
You definitely want to go with current production 12 (12.2.1).
Those links will outline the new features in 12c.

Also, consider stopping by the [ADF Enterprise Methodology Group](https://sites.google.com/site/oracleemg/adf) and ask the question there. Not sure what you mean by "lack of decent resources". In addition to the voluminous docs, there is the [Youtube ADF channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMPGSCAmnzI&list=PLAHRwp0XMMCky20UnNBM9AEyPMbaECCbC) with many recorded tutorials, [blogs, books,](https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/adf-links/adf-blogs-and-books) and [in-depth, comprehensive training](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=609&get_params=dc:D76564,clang:EN). Take a look at my [aggregation site](https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/Home) to see what else there is.

Consider this - the largest customer of ADF is Oracle itself. ALL Oracle tools, consoles and the like, including Fusion Applications, a far, far larger dev effort than anything you could possibly be planning, are all based on ADF.

ADF offers two different means of interacting with databases (JPA and Business Components, with declarative tooling support built into JDeveloper) and native support for creating and consuming SOAP and REST. Its data control data abstraction layer makes connecting to and working with back end services and data source much easier. There is tooling support for eclipse as well. Also, the [Mobile product](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/overview/index.html) allows development of hybrid applications for iOS And Android using similar concepts as ADF Desktop. It is the only end-to-end seamlessly integrated framework that I know of, that does not require piecing together different bits from different vendors and hope to make it all work together in a coherent fashion.

Is there a learning curve? Of course, as is true with any new framework. ADF is a framework, and like any framework, requires you to do it "their way." 
It also has built in support for git, maven and continuous integration.

I think [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/how_do_i_start_learning_oracle_adf_and_jdeveloper) is good to get started. Also consider sending one developer to the five day online training course to more fully evaluate the product (link above).
 In addition, I would suggest you look at the ADF youtube videos as well.

I respectfully disagree with Marcus. 1. not sure what he means by "weird." 2. Developers with JEE experiences (servlets, JSP, JSF, JavaBeans, ORM) will find many things familiar and lots of repetitive, predictable code already in the framework, making it easier for them to concentrate on logic and functionality more than infrastructure and plumbing.

Comment: Developers with JEE experiences come to ADF with a sort of "Managed Bean Love", building their logic on ValueChangeEvents, JSF converters, while the "natural way" with ADF is to replace all of these inside BC Layer (as RowImpl setters, BC Formatters etc ).
I call it weird because lot of the functionality in JSF overlaps with what you get in BC Components.

Comment: I would agree that if JEE developers are "in love" with managed beans doing everything, then they will have some habits to break/unlearn. At my client 2 weeks ago this issue came up. But as they (mostly) were good developers they could see and understand the shift. It did require the trainer to be able to help them make the leap.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Joe I've enhanced my question to reflect my confusion with 12c and 11g

Comment: I am not familiar with Retail so can't say for sure. This is a question you should post on JDev OTN: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=83   where the PMs and Oracle ACES will answer your q. Also a Q for your Oracle Salerep and Sales Engineer. If it is only a matter of interacting with tables, then you could use 12c, but then run into the issue of where to run it - as you can't run two versions of ADF Runtime Libs on same WLS Domain. You would need to create a separate WLS domain to rub ADF 12c runtime.

Comment: If you go the JS route at least take a look at Oracle JET: http://oraclejet.org